# D3 - How to turn rollup with multiple nestings into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

In my data, I did the following rollup using D3:

```
datag = d3.rollup(kmeans_data, v => d3.sum(v,d=>d.value),d=>d.attribute,d=>d.label)
```

The output for this is a InternMap with InternMaps.
When my roullpup has only one filtering, I can turn it into an
array using something like:

```
[...datag].map(([attribute, value]) => ({ attribute, value }));
```

My question is how to do it if I have multiple nestings, since the code above only turns the first InternMap into an array, thus, I get an Array of InternMaps, instead of an Array of Arrays.

Comment: D3 Rollup is just a wrapper of Array.reduce, so I suppose you need to write a recursive reducer of your own... You can also take a look at similar routines of lodash: https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are/were after is [flatRollup](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-flatgroup)

```
athletes = [
  {name: "Floyd Mayweather", sport: "Boxing", nation: "United States", earnings: 285},
  {name: "Lionel Messi", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Argentina", earnings: 111},
  {name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Portugal", earnings: 108},
  {name: "Conor McGregor", sport: "MMA", nation: "Ireland", earnings: 99},
  {name: "Neymar", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Brazil", earnings: 90},
  {name: "LeBron James", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States",  earnings: 85.5},
  {name: "Roger Federer", sport: "Tennis", nation: "Switzerland", earnings: 77.2},
  {name: "Stephen Curry", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States", earnings: 76.9},
  {name: "Matt Ryan", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 67.3},
  {name: "Matthew Stafford", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 59.5}
]

datax = d3.flatRollup(athletes, v => d3.sum(v,d=>d.earnings),d=>d.nation,d=>d.sport)
console.log(datax);
```